# How to print a pdf file via c#

Tags: c#

I'm beginner developer. I'm building a windows desktop form application like a notepad. The user will fill contact info and add text when the information is loaded, the user should be able to save the form as .pdf file and the possibility to print out the entire form directly, same as it was loaded. Which the best and quick alternative to accomplish this on c#?

Save a .pdf file at least on C#

Comment: what you have tried. show your code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/itext7

Answer (score -1):

You can use an installed PDF Reader by this:

```
Process prcs = new Process();
prcs.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    Verb = "print",
    FileName = @"your file path"
};
prcs.Start();
```

Comment: ok. I see the fastest and easiest way is allow my PDF reader soft manage the printing instead customize everything on my own C# soft.